# How to combine multiple PCollections together and give it as input to a ParDo function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have some six PCollections as KV. I want to do ParDo on another PCollection by giving the combined (6) PCollections as sideInput.

I tried giving all 6 PCollections as separate sideInput as below

```
PCollection<TableRow> OutputRows = MyCollection.apply(ParDo.withSideInputs(Inp1, Inp2,...)
    .of(new DoFn<KV<String, String>, TableRow>() {
        ...
    }
```

But its throwing OutOfMemoryError as the heap space exceeds. Please advice on how to combine the PCollections to give as input to another PCollection.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Dataflow provides several ways of joining.

`PCollection`s used as a side-input are broadcast to the worker and loaded into memory. This sounds like what you're doing and would explain the OOM if the sum of the `PCollection` sizes is too big.

You mentioned that the values are keyed -- another option is to use a [CoGroupByKey](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/join/CoGroupByKey).

To do this, you would create a `KeyedPCollectionTuple` with all of your `PCollection`s, then you would get a result which had all the values for each key. Using a `CoGroupByKey` like this will shuffle your data around so that the ParDo that consumes the result for a given key will only need to read in the associated values:

```
PCollection<KV<K, V1>> inp1 = ...;
PCollection<KV<K, V2>> inp2 = ...;

final  TupleTag<V1> t1 = new  TupleTag<>();
final  TupleTag<V2> t2 = new  TupleTag<>();
PCollection<KV<K, CoGbkResult>> coGbkResultCollection =
  KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(t1, inp1)
                       .and(t2, inp2)
                       .apply(CoGroupByKey.<K>create());

PCollection<T> finalResultCollection =
  coGbkResultCollection.apply(ParDo.of(
   new  DoFn<KV<K, CoGbkResult>, T>() {
     @Override
     public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      KV<K, CoGbkResult> e = c.element();
      Iterable<V1> pt1Vals = e.getValue().getAll(t1);
      V2 pt2Val = e.getValue().getOnly(t2);
      ... Do Something ....
     c.output(...some T...);
   }
 }));
```